# Why do any TFT-LCD commands get ignored after an extern function is called?

Tags: arduino, esp32, lcd, arduino-c++

My project is to build a data logger. I'm using an ESP32 and a 2,8" SPI TFT-LCD with an ILI9341 controller and integrated SD-card slot along with some other sensors. I us the Arduino IDE because of the libraries and documentation. As seen in the code below, before starting the SD card everything works fine. However, after the SD card gets started (or any other function that originated from an included library gets called) any commands for the TFT simply get ignored. What is the reason for this?

The following code is just for testing purposes but illustrates the problem fairly well:

```
//Included Libraries  
#include <SPI.h>  
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>  
#include <Adafruit_ILI9341.h>  
#include <SD.h>

//used Pins on ESP32  
#define TFT_CS 15  
#define TFT_RST 0  
#define TFT_DC 2  
#define TFT_MOSI 23  
#define TFT_CLK 18  
#define TFT_MISO 19     

//initialize Library as "tft" with used Pins  
Adafruit_ILI9341 tft = Adafruit_ILI9341(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_MOSI, TFT_CLK, TFT_RST, TFT_MISO);  

void setup() {
  
  Serial.begin(115200);  
  
  tft.begin();  
  tft.fillScreen(ILI9341_BLACK);  

  tft.drawCircle(100,100, 20, ILI9341_BLUE);  

  //at this point, a blue circle appears on the Display  

  //Start SD Card. If successfull draw red circle  
  
  if(SD.begin()){  

    tft.drawCircle(100,200, 20, ILI9341_RED);  
    
    Serial.print("red circle");
  
    //"red circle" appears in the serial monitor but no circle on the display, only a blue one   
  }  
}

void loop() {
}
```

Funnily, if I set a flag manually it works fine. Only if extern functions are called (like `SD.begin()`) the commands get ignored.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Tri The board is a ESP32 DEVKIT V1 with this Pinout [link](https://duino4projects.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/GPIO-pins-of-ESP32-DEVKIT.jpg). The TFT and the SD Card are on the same board similar to this one: [link](https://www.amazon.de/ILI9341-Display-Seriell-Arduino-Raspberry/dp/B07YTWRZGR/ref=sr_1_3?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=11RZ64TL7JRHD&keywords=2.8%22+TFT+LCD&qid=1654778754&sprefix=2.8%22+tft+lcd%2Caps%2C83&sr=8-3).

Answer (score 0):

I would make this a comment if I could. My suspicion is that you are using the pin that the ESP32 uses for the SD card's chip select for the TFT as well (assuming the ESP32 uses SPI for the SD card too). The ESP probably brings that pin out so that you can use it if you aren't using the SD card. I could be wrong, of course, but my guess would still be that this is the result of some hardware-level interference between the two devices. Can you link the specific ESP32 board you're using so we can see what pins are being used?

Edit: Thanks for that extra info. I realized your problem might be that external functions might be changing the pin settings for some of the pins that you have allocated for the tft e.g. if TFT_MOSI is originally configured as an output, but a different function configures it as an input, then communicating with the LCD would no longer work. Maybe try reinitializing the tft object after that SD.begin() and see if that works?